# Spark JobEnd Listner moving source file from hdfs path causes file not found exception

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming

spark version: 2.3

- Spark streaming application is streaming from a hdfs path

  ```
    Dataset<Row> lines = spark
    .readStream()
    .format("text")
    .load("path");
  ```
- And after some transformations of Data, for one file, the job supposed to be in succeeded status.
- Job  listner is added for job end and it moves the file when it's triggered.

  ```
  @Override
  public void onJobENd(SparkListenerJobEnd jobEnd) {
  // Move source file to some other location which is finished processing. 
  }
  ```
- Files gets moved successfully to another location.  But at the same time (exact time stamp) spark throws following file not found exception.This happens at random and  cannot be replicated. But happens often
- Even though the particular job is ended spark is still referring to the file somehow.
- How to make sure once a job is ended file is not referred by spark and avoid this file not found issue
- I could found that on :[here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-scheduler-SparkListener.html)

> SparkListenerJobEnd
>
> ```
> DAGScheduler does cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop, handleTaskCompletion, failJobAndIndependentStages, and markMapStageJobAsFinished.
> ```

- [Same question with different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026583/how-to-avoid-file-not-found-exception-when-spark-streaming-from-hdfs)

**Exception:**

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: <filename>
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1853)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1825)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getBlockLocations(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteExc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug in spark 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24364
Mail thread; http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201805.mbox/%3cJIRA.13161366.1527070555000.13725.1527070560256@Atlassian.JIRA%3e
Fix: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21408/commits/c52d972e4ca09e0ede1bb9e60d3c07f80f605f88

Fixed versions: 2.3.1/2.4.0